# Prove that if $f(x)$ is convex and nonnegative, then $g(x)=(f(x))^2$ is convex too

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let
$$f: \mathbb{R}^d \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}\\
g: \mathbb{R}^d \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
such that
$$f(x)\geq 0 \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^d.$$

Prove that if $f(x)$ is convex, then $g(x)=(f(x))^2$ is convex, too.

Comment: Note that the nonnegativity of $f$ is *essential* for this to be true. I've edited the title to include it.

Comment: I think the question is now abit different than it was before..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the definition of convexity: for every $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $\lambda \in [0,1]$
$$g(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)=[f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)]^2$$
and by the convexity of $f$ and $f\ge0$
$$g(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\le[\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)]^2$$
finally by the convexity of $x^2$
$$g(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\le\lambda f(x)^2+(1-\lambda)f(y)^2=\lambda g(x)+(1-\lambda)g(y)$$
The last expression is precisely the convexity of $g(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Without loss of generality you can assume $d=1$ -- a function is convex on $\mathbb R^d$ iff it is convex on every line through $\mathbb R^d$.

Then just compute $g''(x)$ and see that it cannot be negative given your assumptions.

Comment: How can you be sure that $g''(x)$ exists? $f(x)$ is not supposed differentiable.

Comment: @mrprottolo: Hmm, good point. I suppose one can still get through by approximating intervals of $f$ smoothly using the Weierstrass approximation theorem, but the details might be unpleasant.

Comment: This solution is very very limited, as it assumes f is differentiable (in fact twice diff'ble !). Also I don't see how the author hopes to save it using the WAT. I'll be interested in seeing the "unpleasant details" of this magic.